# How To Enable Azure Cosmos DB Preview Features (aggregation pipeline and Mongodbv3.4) via Powershell?

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I would like to enable Aggregation Pipeline and MongoDBv3.4 preview features programmatically through AzureRM Powershell.

[image]

So far I've tried to do that through Azure ARM Template and `Set-AzureRmResource` command without any success.

`Set-AzureRmResource`:

```
$updateDBProperties = @{
        "capabilities" = @(@{"Name" = "EnableAggregationPipeline"}, @{"Name"= "MongoDBv3.4"}) 
};

# also tried without luck
# $updateDBProperties = @{
#       "capabilities" = @("EnableAggregationPipeline", "MongoDBv3.4")
# };

# won't work
Set-AzureRmResource -ResourceType "Microsoft.DocumentDb/databaseAccounts" `
    -ApiVersion "2015-04-08" `
    -ResourceGroupName "my-resource-group" `
    -Name "my-cosmosdb-development" `
    -Properties $updateDBProperties
```

Through arm template without luck:

```
{
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {
    "cosmosDBName": {
    "type": "string"
    },
    "location": {
    "type": "string"
    },
    "locations": {
    "type": "array"
    }
},
"variables": {},
"resources": [
    {
    "name": "[parameters('cosmosDBName')]",
    "type": "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts",
    "apiVersion": "2015-04-08",
    "location": "[parameters('location')]",
    "kind": "MongoDB",
    "properties": {
        "consistencyPolicy": {
        "defaultConsistencyLevel": "Session",
        "maxIntervalInSeconds": 5,
        "maxStalenessPrefix": 100
        },
        "databaseAccountOfferType": "Standard",
        "locations": "[array(parameters('locations'))]",
        "capabilities": [
        {
            "name": "EnableAggregationPipeline"
        },
        {
            "name": "MongoDBv3.4"
        }
        ]
    }
    }
],
"outputs": {}
}
```

We load the arm template above through Powershell. The cosmos db get created but the preview features is not enabled:

```
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -TemplateFile $templateDirectory"/azureCosmosDB.json" -TemplateParameterObject $templateParameterObject -Name $templateParameterObject.cosmosDBName;
```

Comment: Could you check the `capabilities` in the resource explorer of your mongo db? The  two properties existing or not?

Comment: @JoyWang you mean inside the generated automation script (arm template)? No it's not there even after I ran all of the above.

Comment: I mean after executing your command, you could check the capabilities of your mongo db in the `resources.azure.com`, if there are the two `name` properties over there? If they exist, I think it is successful.  if you check the button in the portal, they are not enabled, it may be a bug, because I have seen a similar issue in web app.

Comment: Those two properties are not generated in the resources.azure.com. It's only generated when I'm using Azure CLI command but not Powershell's AzureRM.

Answer (score 2):

I succeeded to set these capabilities via the command line tool `az`:

```
az cosmosdb update \
   --name my-resource-group \
   --resource-group my-cosmosdb-deployment \
   --capabilities "EnableAggregationPipeline" "MongoDBv3.4"
```

Though it took several minutes. Hope that helps!

Comment: the other preview feature has the label "mongoEnableDocLevelTTL"... just in case someone wants to enable all three

Answer (score 0):

This is achievable with PowerShell by **patching** the CosmosDB account resource. The key is to add the `-UsePatchSemantics` flag to `Set-AzureRmResource` so that it makes an HTTP PATCH request, rather than an HTTP PUT.

```
$db = Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceName "CosmosDB account name" -ResourceGroupName "RG name" | Where-Object -Property ResourceType -eq "Microsoft.DocumentDb/databaseAccounts"

# Enable some optional capabilities/features
$props = @{capabilities = @( @{name="EnableAggregationPipeline"}, @{name="MongoDBv3.4"})}

# Patch the resource with these settings
Set-AzureRmResource -ResourceId $db.ResourceId -ApiVersion "2015-04-08" -PropertyObject $props -UsePatchSemantics
```

Answer (score 0):

To get this working as part of the ARM template, I had to change the *apiVersion* (2015-04-08, in your case) to something more recent:

```
"apiVersion": "2019-08-01",
```

For more information on apiVersion, you can review the MS documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.documentdb/allversions).

However, this currently seems to only be working when initially creating the Cosmos DB with the feature enabled; So far, I didn't find a way to enable it after the resource has been initially provisioned.